# I want call data form subcollection with specific data

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I want call data from subcollection with specific data that I highlight
[image]

```
export class FirebaseService {

    onsiteRef: AngularFirestoreCollectionGroup<Onsiteinterface>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, public ngFireAuth: 
    AngularFireAuth)  { 
        this.onsiteRef = db.collectionGroup('Request', ref => 
        ref.where('Onsite','==','Onsite'));
    }
```